# what is $F_Y(y)$ based on $X_i$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am given random variables $X_i$, where $i=1, 2, \ldots ,n$. They are all independent and have the distribution of $N(0,1)$. I also have a random variable $Y=X_1 + 2X_2 + \cdots + nX_n$ and now I am supposed to find the distribution of a random variable

$$Y^* = \frac{Y-E(Y)}{\sqrt{D(Y)}}$$

What I have already tried is this:

$F_y(Y)=P(Y<y)=P(X_1 + 2X_2 + \cdots + nX_n < y)$, now, since the sum of these random variables is less than $y$, that means that each of them is also less than $y$. Now, if I am correct, I get the following

$P(X_1<y)\cdot P(2X_2 < y)\cdots P(nX_n<y)$ and this is where I get stuck. How do I continue from here and get the cumulative distribution function of each of these variables? Any hints are appreciated, thanks

Comment: "that means that each of them is also less than $y$"... not necessarily, since $X_i$ may be negative.

Comment: @Miguel I totally missed that, thanks. Do you have any other idea on how to approach this problem?

Comment: PS: it is $F_Y(y)$

Comment: Regards @ivana14 . What is $D(Y)$ stands for? thanks.

Comment: @Arief It is dispersion of the random variable $Y$, it can also be written as $Var(Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(X_1 + 2X_2 + \cdots + nX_n < y)$$ is definitely not equal to $$P(X_1<y)\cdot P(2X_2 < y)\cdots P(nX_n<y)$$ since the event $$Y<y$$ is not the same as $$\Big[ (X_1 <y)\ \&\ (2X_2<y)\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ (nX_n<y)\Big].$$

Notice that
\begin{align}
X_1 & \sim N(0,1) \\
2X_2 & \sim N(0,4) \\
3X_3 & \sim N(0,9) \\
& \,\,\,\vdots \\
nX_n & \sim N(0,n^2) \\[5pt]
\text{so } X_1+ 2X_2 + \cdots+nX_n & \sim N(0,1+4+9+\cdots+n^2)
\end{align}

**But you don't need that in order to answer the question:** You just need to know that that sum is normally distributed, and so, since
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{E} \frac{Y - \operatorname{E}(Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(Y)}} = 0 \\[10pt]
& \text{and } \operatorname{var} \frac{Y-\operatorname{E}(Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(Y)}} = 1, \\[10pt]
&\text{we conclude that } \frac{Y-\operatorname{E}(Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(Y)}} \sim N(0,1).
\end{align}

Comment: I understand it much better now, thanks. Only one thing left, when I try to find the distribution of $Y^*$ now, I get the integral $\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdotp \int e^{y^2}dy$.. this is a divergent integral, if I am correct.. What should I do now? thanks

Comment: @ivana14 : Probably you need to explain you you got that. You should get $ \displaystyle \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2/2} \, dy. \qquad $

Comment: yes, that's what I got actually. I corrected a mistake I made. So what are the limits of this integral. If I am correct it goes from $-\infty$ to $x $

Comment: @ivana14 : $$ F_Y(w) = \Pr(Y\le w) = \int_{-\infty}^w  f_Y(y)\,dy. $$

Comment: Which *is* convergent, but *not* resolvable in terms of elementary functions; a well known and somewhat annoying property of the normal distribution.

Comment: @GrahamKemp okay, so do I just leave it as it is or what?

Comment: @ivana14 : You can say that the distribution of $Y$ is identified by saying $$ F_Y(y) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^y e^{-t^2/2} \, dt,$$ or you can say the distribution is $$ \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2/2} \, dy, $$ or you can just say that the distribution of $Y$ is $N(0,1).$ In many contexts, that last is what I would do. But if this is a homework exercise, which answer is appropriate may depend on how the question is phrased. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

The key is that the [sum of a series of independent normally distributed random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Independent_random_variables) is a normally distributed random variable whose mean is the sum of the series' means and variance the sum of the series' variances.

Also if $X_k\sim\mathcal N(0,1^2)$ then $kX_k\sim\mathcal N(0, k^2)$

- Generally: $Z\sim \mathcal N(\mu_Z,\sigma_Z^2)\implies aZ+b\sim\mathcal N(a\mu_Z+b, a^2\sigma^2_Z)$

So, therefore: $$\sum_{k=1}^n k X_k~\sim~\mathcal N\left(0, \sum_{k=1}^n k^2\right)$$

Take it from there.

---

So we have $Y\sim \mathcal N(\mathsf E(Y), \mathsf D(Y))$ for *some* parameters (specifically $0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$ as above).

Given that then since $Y^*$ is a linear function of $Y$, namely $\frac{Y-\mathsf E(Y)}{\surd \mathsf D(Y)}$, therefore ...

Comment: thanks :) so if I got it correctly $Y^*=\frac{2Y}{n(n+1)}$.. how should I get the distribution of $Y^*$ now?

Comment: For any constant $a$, what are $\mathsf E(aY)$ and  $\mathsf {Var}(aY)$? @ivana14

Comment: it's $aE(Y)$ and $aVar(Y)$, but how do those help me get $F(Y^*)$

Comment: It is not. $\mathsf {Var}(aY)=a^2\,\mathsf {Var}(Y)$.  Now what does that mean when $a=1/\sqrt{\mathsf {Var}(Y)}$?

Comment: yes, I made a typo there, thanks for the correction.. then $Var(aY)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to @Graham-Kemp answer.
$$ Y = X_1 + 2X_2 + \cdots + nX_n $$
We can determine the distribution of $Y$ by finding it's moment generating function (*mgf*) : $E[e^{tY}]$.

> The *mgf* of a normal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$
>   is  $$ e^{\mu t + \frac{1}{2}(\sigma t)^2} $$

Since $X_{i}$'s are identical and independent, I may write
$$ \operatorname{mgf}(Y) = E[e^{tY}] = E[e^{tX_{1} + 2tX_{2} + \cdots + ntX_{n}}] = E[e^{tX_{1}}]E[e^{2tX_{2}}]E[e^{3tX_{3}}]\cdots E[e^{ntX_{n}}] $$
$$ \operatorname{mgf}(Y) = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}+\frac{1}{2}(2t)^{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2}(nt)^2} = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2})}$$

So I may conclude that $ Y $ is normally distributed with mean $\mu = 0$ and variance $Var = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2}$. Actually, the information : **$Y$ is normally distributed** is **sufficient** to answer your question. This is because if $X$ is normally distributed (with any mean and variance) then $Z = \frac{X-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $1$. So you can conclude the distribution of $Y^{*} = \frac{Y - \mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}$. 
  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of $\operatorname{mgf}(Y) = \text{a certain function of } t,$ I would write $\operatorname{mgf}_Y(t) = \text{a certain function of } t. \qquad$